# View Revision log message with display suite

Tags: display-suite, nodes

In drupal 7, Is there any way, with or without Display suite, to show the revision log message at the bottom of a view node page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with help of [views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Check the screen shot

[image]

**Update**
Position the view block to show on node page, where view will pick the node id and show the related revision log message.

Comment: check the updated answer if that helps